# Amazon ec2 for hosting java RESTful service with MongoDB as datastore

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to host Java RESTful web service which operates over MongoDB. I am thinking of hosting it in Amazon EC2. Please suggest me what configuration I should use. Here is my systems abstract

- It is a set of java RESTful api which will be consumed by a mobile
  application say XXX (in all platforms).
- XXX is a kind of social networking app focused on user's movie
  preference. A user can search a movie, view its profile write review,
  like,comment others reviews, follow users,etc,.
- I have all movie related information, user profile information and
  reviews stored in MongoDB. Now with only 100 test users and 1L
  movie's information my db size is 0.5 GB.
- I must be capable of supporting large number of requests with low
  latency.

I understand that I can increase RAM & local storage whenever I want. But can I run mongoDB within the same EC2 instance? Want guidance on deciding combinations such as EBS , AWS  Elastic Beanstalk , etc. Please help me with choosing the right configuration.(I would also like to know other better options for hosting my webservice)

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a good fit for StackOverflow as this is a site to help with programming questions, not to select a host configuration for your web application.